# keep only lowest value per row per name

Tags: select, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
Name    Value
A       1
A       2
B       3
B       5
C       1
```

I only want to keep those rows, where the value is the lowest, but per name.

so the result should look like:

```
Name    Value
A       1
B       3
C       1
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` with `idxmin`

```
import pandas as pd

# your data
# =======================
df

  Name  Value
0    A      1
1    A      2
2    B      3
3    B      5
4    C      1

# processing
# =======================
df.groupby('Name', as_index=False).apply(lambda g: g.loc[g.Value.idxmin()])


  Name  Value
0    A      1
1    B      3
2    C      1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.min()` after `groupby`. The `reset_index()` is optional. If you dont use, the `Name` column will be in the index

```
 df_grouped = df.groupby('Name').min().reset_index() 
 df_grouped
     Name  Value
0    A      1
1    B      3
2    C      1
```